# How to query where same id has different value in specific column Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned table:

```
ID      Val1
1       AVD1R
1       ART1R
2       CFD4E
3       DER1R
3       DER1F
```

I want to fetch those records where same `ID` is more than one time with different `Val1`.

Required Output:

```
ID      Val1
1       AVD1R
1       ART1R
3       DER1R
3       DER1F
```

I have tried this:
`select id, Val1 from Table1 where count(Val1)>1 group by id;` But it didn't work.

Comment: Use a simple group by on id and where count(*) > 1

Comment: @SloanThrasher I have tried this `select id, Val1 from Table1 where count(Val1)>1 group by id;` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why are the rows with ID=3 not in the result?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Because both the Value in `Val1` column for `ID=3` are same.

Comment: *DER1**R*** is the same as *DER1**F***?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Sorry my bad.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank, I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i have change my answer to:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 
  ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.VAl1 <> t2.Val1;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> select * from Table1;
+----+-------+
| id | VAl1  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | AVD1R |
|  1 | ART1R |
|  2 | CFD4E |
|  3 | DER1R |
|  3 | DER1F |
+----+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1
    -> INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.VAl1 <> t2.Val1;
+----+-------+
| id | VAl1  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | ART1R |
|  1 | AVD1R |
|  3 | DER1F |
|  3 | DER1R |
+----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Comment: `Count(*)` will not work because i have many other column too in the table but i want to compare `ID` with `Val1`. I Want only those records where `Val1` is different for the same `ID`.

Comment: Did you see the new Answer without count() :-)

Comment: You will get duplicates, if there are more than two rows per ID.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel - thanks - to prevent duplications you can add **group by id , t1.Val1;**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT ID, Val1, COUNT(*) AS Cn FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID, Val1) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS Cn FROM Table1 GROUP BY ID
) AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.Cn <> b.Cn
```

Comment: I want only those rows where there are same multiple `ID` but with different `Val1`.

Comment: @Rahul shah -  sorry, i have change my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are the others columns are.

But in SQL Server:

```
select distinct a.id,val1 from
(
select id,val1
from different
)a
inner join
(
select id,count(id) as cnt
from different 
group by id
having count(*)>1
 ) b
  on  a.id=b.id
```